# use mysql functions for multiple databases with same pattern name

Tags: mysql, function, proc, information-schema, routines

Can I import Mysql function and use it for multiple database with same pattern name without import that function any more ?

I know Mysql save function in two table :

`information_schema.ROUTINES` and `mysql.proc`

Does anyone have an idea to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Every stored procedure is associated with its `schema` or `database`.
So long as the SPs are just routines but not depended on table data, one can happily call them from anywhere.

And if the SPs are intended to calculate based on table data, then you definitely need that `database` qualifier while defining the SP body.
I.e. instead of calling
 `select count(*) from routines;`,
you require to call
`select count(*) from information_schema.routines;`.

If you look into the table structure of both `routines` and `proc` you can find a column `routine_schema` and `db` respectively which point to target database of the SPs.

Unless you define SP bodies, which are table data related, in this way
you definitely have to redefine them in your database environment.

More important thing is that, you again require privileges to *access* and *execute* such cross database SPs.